# Idea for an application similar to snapchat

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, web

I have just thought about an idea that is similar to snapchat and would like to know what I should do next. I am a non-tech individual and thus would like your help in advising me how one would begin creating an application similar to snapchat? What expertise do I look into for hiring a developer? Ruby on Rails? HTML5? Python? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a question for StackOverflow

Comment: Sorry Semyon, I apologise. I asked somebody that question and they directed me to ask it over in this community. Once again, apologies.

Comment: There is nothing to apologies for, it's ok:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails for mobile application? HTML5 can be an option for multiple platforms so that you dont need develop for android, IOS and Microsoft Mobile. Otherwise, you need someone who can code Android, IOS or C#.